# Update a table's field using another table's field to map it with third table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update, case, talend

[image]

I have 3 tables : **landmark, trans and output.** Schema is test schema. **Green are the tables,Blue highlighted are the columns. Mapping can be done between a country and a region.**
I have home_country which is having a home_region as null right now.**I need to find the value for the home_region for that home_country which has home region as null.**

The table should get updated 
if **landmark.pgs_country = output.home_country** then **set landmark.region = output.home_region.**

But if it finds no match for the country **US-GM** in the **output table** with the **landmark - country_name** then it should
map it with **trans table** to check

if **output.home_country = trans.ib_country**, then take trans.xperia_country for that match and equate it with landmark.country_name ie **trans.xperia_country =  landmark.country_name** and **set landmark.region = output.home_region** to find the home_region for the country US-GM.
So basically the update must **set landmark.region = output.home_region**.

How do I update this for the output table?

Comment: The home_region is not always null.My joins initially are between l.pgs_country = o.home_country. pgs_country is not always null. If it is null then I have to join between o.home_country = t.ib_country so that I can get the value of t.xperia_country. Once I get the value of t.xperia_country, I then have to join between l.country_name = t.xperia_country to get the o.home_region. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/10f68/1) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
WITH possible_joins AS (
SELECT
    o.home_country
    , COALESCE(l1.region, l2.region) AS region
FROM
    output o
    LEFT JOIN landmark l1 ON l1.pgs_country = o.home_country
    LEFT JOIN trans t ON t.ib_country = o.home_country
    LEFT JOIN landmark l2 ON l2.country_name = t.xperia_country
WHERE
    o.home_region IS NULL
) 
UPDATE
    output o
SET
    home_region = p.region
FROM
    possible_joins p
WHERE
    o.home_country = p.home_country
    AND o.home_region IS NULL;
```

This could be done in a much easier way, if you could define more rules in your model, meaning impose a better integrity. I'm clearly not saying 'you have to', I even suppose you can't (or maybe this hole thing is about working on it in the first place). I just want to explain, the use of those left joins, as it seems that you can't take anything for granted.

Comment: The above answer is if home_region is always but in my data the home_region is not always null.My joins initially are between l.pgs_country = o.home_country. pgs_country is not always null. If it is null then I have to join between o.home_country = t.ib_country so that I can get the value of t.xperia_country. Once I get the value of t.xperia_country, I then have to join between l.country_name = t.xperia_country to get the o.home_region. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/10f68/1) for it.

Comment: @user1538020 Updated my answer according to your new details.